# Solution to trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I wonder that the solution to the following equation:

> If $0\le x,y\le\pi$, solving the equation $\cos(x-y)=\cos(2x)$ for $x=?$.

My attempted solutions are $x=\frac{y+2k\pi}{3}$ for $k=0,1$.

Am i right? I'm not sure about that ;(

Give some comment. Thank you!

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$$\cos(x-y)-\cos2x=2\sin\dfrac{2x+x-y}2\sin\dfrac{2x-(x-y)}2$$

Finally $\sin z=0\implies z=n\pi$ for any integer $n$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\cos(u)=\cos(v)$ iff $u=\pm v $ plus a multiple of $2\pi$, we have $x-y=\pm 2x +2\pi k$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. If we choose $"+"$, $x-y=2x+2\pi k$, $x=-y-2\pi k$. Such $x,y$ cannot satisfy $0\le x,y\le \pi$. So the sign is $"-"$: $x-y=-2x+2\pi k$, so $3x=y+2\pi k$. The only possible $k$ is $0,1$. So either $x=y/3$ or $x=(y+2\pi)/3$ and $y\le \pi$.

Comment: If k is negative, you will get solutions when the sign is "+".

Comment: Which ones? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I think the answer I gave contains the whole case-analyses.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about the limitations on y being less than $\pi$. Also this plot shows the validity of the solution: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b6nwnumx5d